# options variable is undefined

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm creating my first plugin and having some challenges.  I define a couple global variables: defaults and options.  I'm following the pattern for a plugin like so:

```
 (function ( $ ) {
   var defaults;
   var options;

   $.fn.button_carousel = function(options){
    console.debug("initializing button carousel");

    defaults = {
      days_in_month: 0,
      starting_day: 0,
      days_with_appointments: null,
      btnAppointmentFontColor: "#556b2f"          
    };



    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    console.debug("options: days_in_month: " + options.days_in_month +
                "options: staring_day: " + options.starting_day +
                "options: days_with_appointments: " + options.days_with_appointments);
    ...

    HighlightDays();

 return this.each(function(){
     console.log(options);
  });     
};

 function HighlightDays()
 {
    if(options.days_with_appointments != undefined && options.days_with_appointments != null)
    {
       ...
    }
 }
}( jQuery ));
```

Check out the debug statement.  It prints out the values of each property as expected. However, when I call function HightlightDays(), the condition of the if statement throws up an error stating options variable is undefined.  How can that be? I declare it as a global variable so it can be accessed everywhere.  Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I call function HightlightDays(), the condition of the
>   if statement throws up an error stating options variable is undefined.
>   How can that be? I declare it as a global variable so it can be
>   accessed everywhere.

`options` is `undefined`. `options` is defined within scope of instance of `$.fn.button_carousel` as `$.extend({}, defaults, options)` when assigned to `options` identifier when `$.fn.button_carousel()` is called.

You can pass `options` to `HighlightDays()`

```
HighlightDays(options)
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/tqwIzaqin0HFHweE9h41?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

adding to the guest answer , if you tend to use it further in your functions too you can do it like `window.options` so that you can use it anywhere Scope wouldn't get limited to one function .